# How to match regex in contents from file in python?

Tags: python, regex

This forum is full of similar questions, so here is mine:

```
import re 
import subprocess 
rx = re.compile("(?m)^\(cpu\)\(.*\)") 
output = subprocess.run(["cat","/proc/cpuinfo"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
lines = output.stdout.decode('utf-8') 
r = rx.search(lines) 
if r: 
  print(r.groups())
```

I expect this snipped to find some `cpu` in the multi-line file, but nothing is shown.
(The actual code that fails for me looks of course different, but this is the simplest test case that fails for me, and I can not figure out why...)

Comment: Can you add to the question what `lines` contains?

Comment: Yeah, well, the content of /proc/cpuinfo of course.

Comment: not everyone has ready access to /proc/cpuinfo though, so you should include an example here.

Comment: Why are you using `subprocess` to obtain the contents of a file?  That's quite a complex alternative to [`os.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Answer (score 0):

I think the right regex is "(?m)^cpu\(.*\)", you can try it again.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `(cpu)` string in `/proc/cpuinfo`. I think you're trying to search for `cpu family`:

```py
import re
import subprocess

rx = re.compile(r"cpu family\s*:\s*(.*)")
output = subprocess.run(["cat","/proc/cpuinfo"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
lines = output.stdout.decode('utf-8')

for cpu in rx.findall(lines):
    print(cpu)
```

Prints on my computer:

```
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
```